# How to extract money value from "grossing" string in IMDbPY

Tags: python, regex, string, numbers, imdbpy

I would like to extract a money value when using [IMDbPY](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/) to extract datas from IMDB.

My problem is that IMDbPY returns results in the following format, what is a unicode string:

```
In : movie['business']['gross'][0]
Out: u'$134,966,411 (USA) (11 May 1997)'
```

Also, the date is sometimes present, sometimes not.

Can you help me **how to extract the number from this string, without accidentally recognising the date/year part**?

The currency symbol and the country code are not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.match` with this pattern:

```
r"\$([1-9][0-9,]+)"
```